# Put EMA in RSI indicator by script, not by add-indicator function?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I like to write a script with a RSI within an EMA.
Both simple scripts are working for themselves. But together I'm failing at the source for the EMA.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

//RSI
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")

//EMA55
lenE55 = input(55, minval=1, title="Length EMA55")
srcE55 = input(<I want 'rsi' instead of 'close' here>, title="Source EMA55")
outE55 = ema(srcE55, lenE55)
plot(outE55, title="EMA55", color=#ffff00, linewidth=2, transp=13)
```

If I use just the RSI script in the chart and choose "Add Indicator/Strategy on RSI ..." I can choose my EMA-indicator (like in the script part //EMA55).
In the settings there will be in the tab "Inputs" under "Source EMA55" not (only) the typical "close". There is now "RSI" (the shorttitle) – you can also choose all other indicators that are in the chart as source and open, high, low, etc.!

How can I implement this in my script?
If I try to replace "close" in

```
srcE55 = input(close, title="Source EMA55"
```

with "rsi" – or even with "RSI" – which makes no sense because I'm in the script right now – I end up with errors.
I don't understand how to use the RSI part as base source for the EMA part.

I wouldn't care if I had to use the add-function for just another indicator but my goal is to be able to use the fill function or design my default indicator sets without adding other indicators later for my final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't panic and think logic, you have the answer in your suggestion:

```
srcE55 = input(<I want 'rsi' instead of 'close' here>, title="Source EMA55")
```

Just change the EMA source `close` with your `rsi` source.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

//RSI
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")

//EMA55
lenE55 = input(55, minval=1, title="Length EMA55")
srcE55 = rsi //use rsi as source instead of close
outE55 = ema(srcE55, lenE55) //just change the `close` source with `rsi` source
plot(outE55, title="EMA55", color=#ffff00, linewidth=2, transp=13)
```

[image]

Comment: Now I just have to solve the problem that the EMA is not above the RSI filled band and I can't find a "bring to front" function...

Comment: @zearching what do you mean EMA is not above the RSI filled band? Above the 70 hline? It's quite hard to be above 70, since even RSI is not so ofter greater than that. And what do you want to fill? If you want to bring something in front, just switch plots, the last plot code line will be in front (ex. now the outE55 is in front, but if you move plot(rsi...) on the bottom, then rsi will be in front...

Comment: Sorry @edward, I didn't mean the value. I meant the layer to bring the EMA line on top like you can do this with lines and boxes in the chart by choosing "visual order" -> "bring to front"/"send to back".
I thought that the last plot line will be in front also but in this case it looks like that the fill band (30 to 70 area) of the the RSI is always on top.
If I choose the "Add Indicator/Strategy on RSI ..." with an EMA to a RSI only I can define to put the EMA layer to the front.
I will experiment a little bit in the script with the fill and plot positions.

Comment: @zearching I added an image, looks pretty normal to me, like I said above, the last plot code line will be always in front, play a little bit with plots and see how they react

Comment: @eward just for testing: put the transp value to 0 so there is no more transparency in the 30-to-70-band
`fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=0, title="Background")`
and you will only see the violet RSI over 70 and under 30. The in-between will be covered.
I played around with _plot_ and _fill_ and it works like you said. The last _plot_ will be on top of the other _plots_ and the last _fill_ will be on top of the other _fills_. BUT _fill_ will always be on top over _plot_. That's a little bit annoying.